# Make funciton call in chain on condition

Tags: java, spring

Let's say I'm making request with webClient, and I need to make
`.header("Authorization", String.format("Bearer %s", token))`
call here optional. I mean if `someParam` is `true`, I add authorization header, and if it's false I don't want authorization at all. Is it possible without adding if-else here.

```java
    void function(someParam bool) { 
       String responseString = webClient.post()
                            .uri(requestUrl)
                            .header("Authorization", String.format("Bearer %s", token))
                            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                            .body(Mono.just(request), request.getClass())
                            .retrieve()
                            .bodyToMono(String.class)
                            .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(maxAnalysingTime))
                            .block();
    }
```

I'm not sure how to google this question, because search engine gets triggered by words optional, and conditional, and all I get are articles about Optional class and if-else in java.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to avoid a branch, but you can keep the chaining by calling the `headers` method (which accepts a `Consumer<HttpHeaders>` as its parameter).

```java
webClient.post().uri(requestUrl).headers(headers -> {
    if (someParam) headers.set("Authorization", String.format("Bearer %s", token));
})
// other configuration options...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any other option than to split the chain, using an intermediate variable:

```
    var builder = webClient.post()
                        .uri(requestUrl);
    if (someParam) {
        builder = builder.header("Authorization", String.format("Bearer %s", token));
    }
    String responseString = builder
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .body(Mono.just(request), request.getClass())
                        .retrieve()
                        .bodyToMono(String.class)
                        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(maxAnalysingTime))
                        .block();
```

Comment: Well, thats not the worst option, ty